# Cache-control header shows private always

Tags: caching

According to Sitecore config, if we set `DisableBrowserCaching` to `true`, then the `Cache-control` header value would change to `no-cache, no-store`. In my case, this is not happening and it always shows `Private` as default value.

Has anyone faced similar issue? Any help on this would really be appreciated ?

```
<!--
DISABLE BROWSER CACHING
        If true, all pages will have:
          Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
          Pragma: no-cache
        in the http header

-->
<setting name="DisableBrowserCaching" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Do you see this for all items or only items in Media library? In case Media Library only then you will have to set MediaResponse.Cacheability to public

Comment: @JTC what version of Sitecore are you using? If it's 8.1 Update 2 Support  confirmed that caching not being set correctly is a bug with 8.1 Update 2 MVC (reference number #116813). I implemented a fix for this with some guidance from support and it sets the cache to "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store Pragma: no-cache" when DisableBrowserCaching is true. I can share the code if you need it.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge - You are right, I came across the same issue what you mentioned (reference number #116813). I did check with sitecore support to confirm this . The setting of Cache-control at the IIS level would not work in my case as i have CDN set up for media items . I was told to go with custom processor that is in progress. it would be grateful if have any code for custom processor . Please share

Comment: i was able to achieve this by writing the custom processor

Comment: Sorry for the delay @JTC, It's been a busy week! I've blogged about this now and put my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This is confirmed as a bug in Sitecore 8.1 update 2 (and I believe up to 8.2 update 5) by Sitecore Support (reference number #116813).

It requires an custom pipeline to patched in to resolve the issue. I've blogged about how to fix this here:

http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/disabling-private-cache-sitecore-pages-not-working-sitecore-8-1-8-2/

I don't think there is an official patch/fix for this still.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have addressed this by writing a custom processor with the same implementation what sitecore provided in sitecore 9.X and blogged about this in this link https://jbathecoder.wordpress.com/2018/11/08/sitecore-8-x-disablebrowsercaching-behavior-of-webform-vs-mvc/

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it sorted. good to see this is fixed in 9.x